# How do I get the Latent Space Representation from an LSTM based Autoencoder?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, autoencoder, encoder

I'm trying to construct an encoder to get the latent space in order to plot it. I don't really know if I can get it from the RepeatVector or if I have to add a Dense layer.

Here is my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(16, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape= (x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(LSTM(4, activation='relu', return_sequences=False)) #Encoder
model.add(RepeatVector(X_train.shape[1])) #Latent
model.add(LSTM(4, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)) #Decoder
model.add(LSTM(16, activation='relu', return_sequences=False)) #Decoder
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(X_train.shape[2]))) #Decoder
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the model into two parts (encoder and decoder).
Then, build the encoder using the input and output of the encoder part.
btw the output would be the last layer before using RepeatVector.

```
encoder = Model(inputs, output_from_encoder)
```